# How to make *.ec2-in-st-an-ce.location.compute.amazonaws.com point to ec2-in-st-an-ce.location.compute.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

As the title suggests, I want to add dns record so that *.ec2-in-st-an-ce.location.compute.amazonaws.com point to ec2-in-st-an-ce.location.compute.amazonaws.com.

I tried making hosted zone ec2-in-st-an-ce.location.compute.amazonaws.com and then adding record for * in route53 but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You do not own the `amazonaws.com` domain, so you will not be able to do that.

The domain names such as `ec2-11.22.33.44.region.compute.amazonaws.com` map directly to the IP addresses shown in the name.

If you wish to point an IP address to an Amazon EC2 instance you will need to add an `A-Record` to **a domain that you own and control**.